# Find the minimal $t$, $t\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $113^t \equiv 1\bmod(455)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find the minimal $t$, $t\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $113^t \equiv 1\bmod(455)$.

I received this problem in introductory number theory so I have tried to use the basic properties of modular congruences and other division-based properties. So I have tried identifying the following,
Using the property that $a\equiv b\bmod(n)$ and $m\mid n$ then $a\equiv b\bmod(m)$ and then,
\begin{align}
113^t \equiv1\bmod(5) \\
113^t \equiv1\bmod(7) \\
113^t \equiv1\bmod(13) \\
\end{align}
Then we get a system of linear congruences and then maybe if we let $113^t$ be $x$ then we can get $x$ and find a minimal $t$ satisfying that $x$. But does not seem to really work.
Anyway, you could use Eulers theorem and the Eulers totient function and get $t=288$ which I don't know if is correct since I think $288$ is actually the maximal maybe(not sure)? But I want to solve this with more elementary methods without such concepts.

Comment: Actually, $113^{12}\equiv 1 \bmod 455$, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254898/how-can-i-get-the-least-n-such-that-17n-equiv-1-mod100), or many others.

Comment: Note that when you are working modulo $5$, $113$ is the same as $3$; modulo $7$, $113=1$, and modulo $13$, $113=9=-4$.

Answer (score 0):

If $113^{288}\equiv1\pmod{455}$ then $113^{144}\equiv \pm 1\pmod{455}$. You can verify that $113^{144}\equiv  1\pmod{455}$ so  $113^{12^2}\equiv  1\pmod{455}$ and
$113^{12}\equiv  1\pmod{455}$. Since  $113^{6}\equiv 274\pmod{455}$. You find now that the minimum exponent is $12$.